# SQL syntax for countif to be inserted

Tags: sql, pivot-table, countif

I have a table (tbl2) [i have 4 columns with feedback attributes listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06VTK.png). I need to generate a pivot table like syntax in mysql. Need output somewhat like this [pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cTzu.png). I am currently trying this

```
INSERT INTO 1 (`BAD/GOOD`, `PRICE YES`, `PRICE NO`, `TOTAL PRICE`) SELECT "BAD",COUNT(*) WHERE tbl2.PRICE="BAD" AND tbl2.Churn="YES",COUNT(*) WHERE tbl2.PRICE="BAD" AND tbl2.Churn="NO",COUNT(*) WHERE tbl2.PRICE="BAD" FROM tbl2_customers_churn
```

and also tried insert into as values

```
INSERT INTO 1 VALUES ("BAD",COUNT(*) FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.PRICE="BAD" AND tbl2.Churn="YES",COUNT(*) FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.PRICE="BAD" AND tbl2.Churn="NO",COUNT(*) FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.PRICE="BAD")
```

for bad and good count separately

Any advise on how to tackle this in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want logic more like this:

```
INSERT INTO 1 (`BAD/GOOD`, `PRICE YES`, `PRICE NO`, `TOTAL PRICE`)
    SELECT 'BAD',
            SUM(CASE WHEN tbl2.PRICE = 'BAD' AND tbl2.Churn = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
            SUM(CASE WHEN tbl2.PRICE = 'BAD' AND tbl2.Churn = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
            SUM(CASE WHEN tbl2.PRICE = 'BAD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM tbl2_customers_churn tbl2;
```

Or a little more simply:

```
    SELECT 'BAD',
            SUM(CASE WHEN tbl2.Churn = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
            SUM(CASE WHEN tbl2.Churn = 'NO' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
            COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl2_customers_churn tbl2
    WHERE tbl2.PRICE = 'BAD'
```